# Interceptor that wraps around Java EE beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

Is it possible in Java EE to write an interceptor that wraps around Java EE beans like it is possible with Spring and AspectJ?

Comment: Hi, did you try using a search engine before asling this question? If not why not, if so what were the search criteria/terms you used? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `@Interceptors` annotation:

[Oracle Doku](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html)